# How do you rerun java code from document.ready in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am new to javascript and jsp. Below is my javascript that I have on my jsp page. On document.ready, it's supposed to check if the setup is complete by calling my java code. Then I put my java setupComplete variable into a javascript variable and if the setup is complete, then the summary page shows, otherwise the setup page should show. When the user clicks the Done button, it saves the data that the checked to the database and then hides the setup div and then it's supposed to show the summary div. However, the page seems to reload when I have it do this, and then it still thinks that setupCompleteJS is false, even though I set it to true twice below and the data does save properly meaning that my java code would give the correct true output if it runs again, so it must not be running again. How do I get my java code to rerun when document.ready reruns?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isClicked = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    <%
    Integer userId = (Integer) Context.getAuthenticatedUser().getUserId();
    String patientId = request.getParameter("patientId");
    SummaryTable summaryTable = new SummaryTable(patientId, userId);
    List<String> sumItems = summaryTable.retrieveUserSummaryItems();
    Boolean setupComplete = sumItems.size() > 0;
    Map<String, List<Object>> sumDataMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (setupComplete) {
        sumDataMap = summaryTable.generateSummaryTable(sumItems);
    }
    %>
    var setupCompleteJS = <%=setupComplete %>;

    if (setupCompleteJS === true) {
        jQuery('#setup').hide();
        jQuery('#summary').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('#summary').hide();
        jQuery('#setup').show();
    }

    jQuery('#setupDoneButton').click(function(){
        <%
        String sumData[]= request.getParameterValues("sumData");
        summaryTable.saveSetup(sumData);
        sumDataMap = summaryTable.generateSummaryTable(sumItems);
        setupComplete = true;
        %>
        setupCompleteJS = true;
        jQuery('#setup').hide();
        jQuery('#summary').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't. Java is executed server-side, everything you write will be executed before the webpage reaches the browser. You can't execute JSP client-side.

Comment: Separately: *"How do I get my java code to rerun when document.ready reruns?"* Why would it re-run? It runs once, when the page is fully loaded (other than images and such).

Comment: what you can do is send a request to your backend  to do whatever you want on `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the `<% %>`'s is only run ***once*** on your server before this HTML file is sent to the client. Your Javascript code runs on the client (in the browser).

If you want to run some Java code on your server every time a button is clicked, you'll need to use AJAX to send a request to your server and write some server code that handles your request.

Here's a tutorial from Oracle on AJAX:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tutorial-jsp-140089.html